# Binding Ajax response to jquery nested array

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to bind ajax response to jquery nested array (Arrays inside main array).
Example explanation of my requirement

```
Ajax Response : {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
```

i want to convert this to jquery arrays as mentioned below.

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7.8.9]]
```

Please let me know any possible way.

Comment: Your ajax response is invalid

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy invalid json you mean

Comment: @madalinivascu Of course yes

Comment: it's just example not actual response. Ok, let me put it this way... Let's assume we have 9 results in ajax response and i want to break them into three items per array in jquery.

Comment: Is it always 3 by 3 ? what happens if you have let's say 10 values from Ajax request ?

Comment: use a for loop and increment the counter from by 3 instead of one

Comment: Please add the stacktrace and code. You may also have a look at [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve the question. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you example case, this will work :

```
var ajaxResponse = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var resultArrays = [];
for (var i = 0; i < ajaxResponse.length; i = i + 3) {
    var tmpArray = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        tmpArray.push(ajaxResponse[i+j]);
    }
    resultArrays.push(tmpArray);
}
```

Comment: Perfect :) Thank you very much

Comment: Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy I can't see your code which you have posted earlier. Please repost the same.